# Cannot push a new local branch to server in GitLab

Tags: git

I locally created a branch by doing

```
 git checkout -b my_branch
```

switched to it

```
 git checkout  my_branch
```

then added files

```
 git add files/
 git commit -m "ssdf"
```

then I wanted to push these files as 'my_branch ' to server by

```
 git push origin my_branch
```

But it did not work, displayed the following

```
 fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
   and the repository exists.
```

so I tried few things on the web,

```
git push -u origin my_branch
```

but did not work.

Comment: You need to set the origin of the repository. Example: git remote add origin  git@<repo_url>:<username>/<repo_name>.git

Comment: What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: @DillonBenson, any example?

Comment: @IsmailBadawi, it said the same error above.

Comment: @alim I have updated my comment

Comment: @DillonBenson. I did as you said and pushed again, but this time I got the following: 
\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. If you no longer wish            to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting .git/hooks/pre-push.\n
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@<repo_url>:<username>/<repo_name>.git'

Comment: @alim Do you intend to use Git LFS (Large file storage) ?

Comment: @DillonBenson. I don't know, but I intended to store only text files, some codes and so on. I don't think they are large usually. So, I don't use Git LFS.

Comment: @alim You should be fine by just removing .git/hooks/pre-push. There's an issue opened on this here: https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/333. This will work as long as you don't intend to store large files, which seems to be probable.

Comment: @DillonBenson. You been helpful, thanks. :)   I solved my problem by discovering my old local repso and create branch and push worked from there. Git  make me quite confusing sometimes.